# circular permutation of similar objects

Tags: r, circular-permutations

I need to an R code for circular permutation of similar objects which defines this code exactly.
The number of circular permutations that can be formed using 'n' objects out of which 'p' are identical and of one kind and 'q' are identical and of another kind.

```
(n-1)!/p!q!
```

This is the best code which I found but it is not exactly what I want

```
library(arrangements)
permutations(x =  c("A","B","C"), freq = c(2,1,1))

output:


    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,] "A"  "A"  "B"  "C" 
 [2,] "A"  "A"  "C"  "B" 
 [3,] "A"  "B"  "A"  "C" 
 [4,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "A" 
 [5,] "A"  "C"  "A"  "B" 
 [6,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "A" 
 [7,] "B"  "A"  "A"  "C" 
 [8,] "B"  "A"  "C"  "A" 
 [9,] "B"  "C"  "A"  "A" 
[10,] "C"  "A"  "A"  "B"     
[11,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "A" 
[12,] "C"  "B"  "A"  "A"
```

I do not want "A" "A" are beside each other.

Comment: Do you mean how many different ways you can visit 'n' objects and then return to the start? Like a travelling salesman?

Comment: Dear @SimonWoodward  this problem is  like Travelling Salesman but with one kind and another kind cities. e.g. you have 5 cities among which 2 London, 2 Hamilton and 1 Auckland. I can not go from London to London.

Comment: Do you need to visit all 5?

Comment: @SimonWoodward Thank you for your code. Yes, I need so. consider sitting around a table for 10 people from 3 countries. People from the same country should not sit beside each other, but all of them should sit at the table.

Comment: Done, I think...

Comment: Do you need the first and last people to be different too? I didn't consider that.

Comment: woooow, @SimonWoodward this is almost what I need to, Thank you. however unfortunately yes, I need the first and the last people to be different.

Comment: just change it to `if (length(remaining)==0 && head(visited,1) != tail(visited,1)){`

Comment: If you like my answer please "tick" it thanks!

Comment: Dear @SimonWoodward Thank you for your code. This is exactly what I need. Best Wishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a recursive function works well for this problem. The function takes the journey so far, figures out which remaining towns are possible to visit next, and then calls itself for each of these. If there are no remaining towns it reports the route.

```r
# recursive function to visit remaining towns
journey <- function(remaining, visited){
  # possible towns to visit next
  possible <- setdiff(remaining, tail(visited, 1))
  if (length(possible)==0){
    if (length(remaining)==0){
      # report and store journey
      print(visited)
      routei <<- routei + 1
      routes[[routei]] <<- visited
    } else {
      # route failed to visit all towns
    }
  } else {
    # loop through options
    for (i in possible){
      # continue journey
      journey(remaining[-match(i, remaining)], c(visited, i))
    }
  }
}

remaining <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C")
visited <- character(0)

routes <- vector("list", length(remaining)^2)
routei <- 0

journey(remaining, visited)
#> [1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "C"
#> [1] "A" "B" "A" "C" "B"
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "B"
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "B" "A"
#> [1] "A" "C" "B" "A" "B"
#> [1] "B" "A" "B" "A" "C"
#> [1] "B" "A" "B" "C" "A"
#> [1] "B" "A" "C" "A" "B"
#> [1] "B" "A" "C" "B" "A"
#> [1] "B" "C" "A" "B" "A"
#> [1] "C" "A" "B" "A" "B"
#> [1] "C" "B" "A" "B" "A"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>